# Meteor Iron Router load template based on dynamic name

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I would like to load a meteor template using iron-router but the template that I'm loading needs to be dynamic, I have tried a couple different approaches but none are working.

My router

```
Router.route('/forms/add-form/:template', {
  name: 'addForm',
  layoutTemplate: 'layoutApp',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('producersList');
  },
  data: function() {
    return Producers.find();
  }
});
```

The router go

```
Router.go('addForm', {template: this.template});
```

The url is fine now I first tried having this in my router

```
name: this.params.template,
```

But that doesn't work I'm now trying the following in my addForm template

```
{{> UI.dynamic template=formToLoad data=myDataContext}}

formToLoad:function(){
    console.log('aaaa ' + this.template);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass data into template in route:

```
Router.route('/forms/add-form/:template', {
  name: 'addForm',
  layoutTemplate: 'layoutApp',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('producersList');
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      producers: Producers.find(),
      formToLoad: this.params.template //here pass the template name
    }
  }
});
```

and in your template:

```
<template name="addForm">
  {{> Template.dynamic template=formToLoad}}
</template>
```

Now if we run:

```
Router.go('addForm', {template: 'someTemplateName'});
```

It should load template with name 'someTemplateName'. Use camelCase syntax for template names because you will get syntax error with 'some-template-name' when you will define helpers or events for template.

Comment: Thanks funny was doing the same thing somewhere else in my code.